# How to run python script on startup with sudo permission on Mac OS

Tags: mac, script, boot, python, sudo

I have created a script with python that basically ping all servers found in my lists. I need this script to be run on startup with sudo permission.

So the question is, How do you run the script on startup with sudo permission

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html). These could be done with root privileges (launchd runs as root).

What I do is to put such scripts in /Library/StartupItems; check this: [Startup Items](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/StartupItems.html). These are run by root authority (see Startup Item Permissions at the bottom). This however, is the old way to do such things. Still works in Lion, though.